# How does the PowerPC instruction 'extsb.' affect the CR register?

Tags: assembly, powerpc

Looking at some ppc disassembly I see:

```
e_lbz    r7, 0(r13)
extsb.   r7,r7
se_beq   some_label
```

[The documentation for `extsb.`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.alangref/idalangref_extsb_instruction.htm) isn't clear on how it affects the condition register.  I'm not sure for what values of `r7` will this branch.

My thinking is that if the value in `r7` has a 0 in the most significant bit then the extsb. instruction will make no change to the value in `r7`. So for any value `r7 >= 0 && r7 <= 127` the equal flag should be set and the `se_beq` should branch.

Comment: Which part is unclear? It will branch if the byte in `r7` is zero.

Comment: What if `r7` is 1? Why would it not branch then? I'll add to my question with examples of how I think certain values should work. How are the condition registers set by the instruction, other instructions explicitly state how the condition registers are modified.

Comment: The flag is set for equal to **zero**, it says so on your link. `1` is not zero obviously, so no branch.

Answer (score 1):

So there are two forms of "extsb" instruction, `extsb` and `extsb.`.

If your code ran `extsb r7,r7`, then `r7` would consist of the signed 64-bit number of equal value to the lower 8 bits of `r7`, interpreted as a signed 8-bit number.

For example if the contents of the low byte of `r7` was `0x00` (signed 8-bit decimal 0), the result of `extsb r7,r7` would be `0x0000 0000 0000 0000` (signed 64-bit decimal 0).

On the other hand, if the low byte of `r7` was `0xff` (signed 8-bit decimal -1), the result would be `0xffff ffff ffff ffff` (signed 64-bit decimal -1).

The difference with the second form, `extsw. r7,r7` is that *as well* as extending `r7`, it will also set some bits in the condition register:

> If the syntax form sets the Record (Rc) bit to 1, the instruction affects the Less Than (LT) zero, Greater Than (GT) zero, Equal To (EQ) zero, and Summary Overflow (SO) bits in Condition Register Field 0.

Your assembler dump is quite odd and unlike ppc asm I've seen before, but it looks like it's trying to do a branch-if-equal, so:

- if the low byte of r7 is 0, it will sign extend 0 and it will branch
- if the low byte of r7 is not zero, it will sign extend the contents and then not branch.